# Convert parse tree into string

Tags: python, nltk

I use NLTK library to generate parse tree from string but then i need to convert this tree to string. How can i do this?

This code generate parse tree

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize, RegexpParser

# Example text
sample_text = "Hello i am student"

# Find all parts of speech in above sentence
tagged = pos_tag(word_tokenize(sample_text))

#Extract all parts of speech from any text
chunker = RegexpParser("""
                    NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>} #To extract Noun Phrases
                    P: {<IN>}            #To extract Prepositions
                    V: {<V.*>}           #To extract Verbs
                    PP: {<p> <NP>}       #To extract Prepositional Phrases
                    VP: {<V> <NP|PP>*}   #To extract Verb Phrases
                    """)

# Print all parts of speech in above sentence
output = chunker.parse(tagged)
print("After Extracting\n", output)
```